# Webpack Not Serving React Component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have created my webpack config file below:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: './src/main.js',
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: '/node_modules/',
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {minimize: true}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: './index.html'
    })
]
};
```

and added all the necessary packages `babel with env and react presets`. I have my `index.html` file and `TestComponent` like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React 16 Webpack Setup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div id="test">

    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TestComponent extends Component {
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>React Setup</h2>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's my `main.js` file where I'm hosting the component:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Test from './TestComponent';

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById("test"));
```

The problem is that when I run this script from `package.json`, I don't get any `output/dist` folder and also the component doesn't render in the browser. On which url do I have to visit to see the output just like with `create-react-app`?

Comment: what is the script you are running?

Answer (score 1):

Import your `<script>` at the bottom of the `<body>` tag in the HTML.

In your case, the browser is reading through the DOM and finding the `<script>` tag **before** it is finding the `<div id="text">` node. What this means is that the browser will read through your script, and then try and render your `<Test/>` component into an HTML node with the `id="test"`. The browser can't find the HTML node with the `id="test"` though because it hasn't read it yet, so it fails.

Make sense? See below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React 16 Webpack Setup</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="test"></div>

    {* import scripts at the bottom of the body *}
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you're still running into issues.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense the way you put it but still the component is not rendered

Comment: I am using HTMLWebPackPlugin but it throws an error about entry point undefined, could this be the issue?

Comment: Should I open the html from dist or src folder, I have tried both still same result

Comment: Where are you using HTMLWebPackPlugin? I don't see that in your webpack config file above, did you post the whole file?

Comment: I have added it now. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Can you also post the "scripts" section of your `package.json`? There's a few updates to your webpack file that I'll make but I need to see the scripts that run it in order to do so.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have fixed this issue, sorry for the delay in response. Have a great one!!